# is it impossible to call a vue js funtion from android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js

I know this question exists in many site, so I followed that answers but now worked.
So I ask this question,
I use vuejs using typescript, and webview in android.
What I want to do is that First, When I click the button in android app, then call the vuejs function.
And Second is calling from js to android. But both are not working.
I checked about all possible solutions but not working for me.
please let me know how to solve this.
I added codes. The url path is right and I can see the page in webview, Home is routed to "http://url/"

*Home js*

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
        <h1>This is an Home page</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Home',
    methods:{
      getAlert(){
        alert(11111);        
      },
      getWebViewAlert(toast:String){
        android.showToast(toast);
      }

    }
})
interface WebAppInterface{  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  showToast(toast: String) : void;
}

declare var android: WebAppInterface;// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

</script>
```

*MainActivity.kt*

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val webviewSetting = binding.webview.settings
        webviewSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webviewSetting.setSupportMultipleWindows(false)
        webviewSetting.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false
        webviewSetting.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webviewSetting.useWideViewPort = true
        webviewSetting.setSupportZoom(false)
        webviewSetting.builtInZoomControls = false
        webviewSetting.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL
        webviewSetting.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        webviewSetting.domStorageEnabled =true
        binding.webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                binding.webview.loadUrl("javascript:getAlert()")
            }
        }
        binding.webview.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        //binding.webview.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this),"android")
        binding.webview.loadUrl(url)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            binding.webview.loadUrl("javascript:getAlert()")
        }
    }

class WebAppInterface internal constructor(c: Context) {
    var mContext: Context
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(toast: String) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    init {
        mContext = c
    }
}
```

*Error in android studio*

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: getAlert is not defined", source: url (1)
```

*updated code*

```
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
let HomeVue; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  mounted(){
    HomeVue = this
  },
  methods:{
    getAlert(){
      return this;
    }

  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: It's not impossible, but Vue instance methods are not available in global scope, just as global scope is not available in the instance's `<template>`. You can assign the instance to a constant in global scope and then you can interact with any of its properties or methods.

Comment: is there any example? it would be more efficient to me?

Comment: I added to make a window varible, but it has an error. is this right way?

Comment: My guess is you'd have to place your var on `mContext`, but I don't know enough about webview and android.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late you joint the discussion. You can mount the app and try accessing it from your android webview code

```
    const resumeApp = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      resume: {
        ...resumeEN,
        address: [resumeEN.country, resumeEN.city, resumeEN.postalCode]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(", "),
        lang: lang,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeLang: function (lang) {
      this.resume = resumeEN;
    },

    renderResumeDocument: function (jsonData) {
      this.resume = jsonData;
    },
  },
});

var mobileAppProxyObj = resumeApp.mount("#app");
```

From your android web view

```
  resumeViewerBinding.webViewResumeViewer.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, weburl: String?) {
                resumeViewerBinding.webViewResumeViewer.loadUrl("javascript:mobileAppProxyObj.renderResumeDocument('Javascript function in webview')")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably TypeScript is the problem. Just stick to ES5 and try it again.

Also, have you loaded the Vue JS runtime in the HEAD of your HTML?

Edit:
You have to include Vue JS in your index.html ... Refer this:
(note the script tag inside head section>

https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/blob/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-hello-world/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your reply, because I'm a starter of javascript. how to check your answer? and how to stick to es5?

Comment: There is a standard version of Javascript (ES5) which is supported by most browsers. There is a newer version of Javascript (ES6) which has lesser support. And there is an alternate version of Javascript called TypeScript which is quite a different thing. It seems you are trying to use typescript(ts) because I can see "<script lang="ts">"

Comment: @Charles I should say your code looks like you are using a ".vue" file which is a Vue single page component. Have you compiled the code and used the distributable app.js file in the HTML?

Comment: ".vue" single page components are not mandatory in Vue. You can just include Vue script inside the HTML and proceed. Also see: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/getting-started-with-vue-js-636ccb989715